# Migracion Django 1.10 a 1.11 Error environment can only contain strings

Tags: python, django, oracle, python-2.x

Recientemente actulize django de su version 1.10 a la 1.11 y la consola me lanza el siguiente error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\nbueno\Envs\nworksdev\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\nbueno\Envs\nworksdev\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\nbueno\Envs\nworksdev\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\nbueno\Envs\nworksdev\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 62, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\nbueno\Envs\nworksdev\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\nbueno\Envs\nworksdev\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 101, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\nbueno\Envs\nworksdev\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 110, in run
    autoreload.main(self.inner_run, None, options)
  File "C:\Users\nbueno\Envs\nworksdev\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 332, in main
    reloader(wrapped_main_func, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nbueno\Envs\nworksdev\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 303, in python_reloader
    exit_code = restart_with_reloader()
  File "C:\Users\nbueno\Envs\nworksdev\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 289, in restart_with_reloader
    exit_code = subprocess.call(args, env=new_environ)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 523, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "c:\python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 959, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
TypeError: environment can only contain strings
```

Al parecer esto simplemente existe cuando la plataforma de sistema operativo es windows ya que en linux el error no existe, pero no puedo identificar si el problema yace en el mismo django o en el python 2.7 a la hora de cargar variables "environment"

Trate de replicar el proyecto desde 0 en django 1.11 y al parecer me da el mismo error cuando cambio de base de datos, utilizo una base de datos oracle y el driver cx_oracle el string de coneccion que utilizo es el siguiente

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': 'DBARS_PROD',
        'USER': 'userhere',
        'PASSWORD': 'passhere',


        }
}
```

si utilizo el sqlite3 que trae por defecto el proyecto corre sin errores.

Comment: Pues si, puede ser cualquier cosa. Empieza verificando tus variables de entorno. Busca que no tengas espacios o falten comillas o cosas asi.

Comment: Bueno, algo que vi es que si uso la base de datos que trae por defecto **sqlite3** la aplicacion corre sin problemas usando 'DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
' pero si conecto una oracle me devuelve ese error

Comment: Revisa entonces tu cadena conexión a Oracle. Y edita tu pregunta para agregar los detalles faltantes, si lo consideras necesario. Te recomiendo, en cualquier caso, que intentes incluir un __[mcve]__.

Comment: DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': 'DBARS_PROD',
        'USER': 'userhere',
        'PASSWORD': 'passhere',
        

        }
}
esta es la cadena de coneccion que utilizo siempre, y esta justo como en la documentacion django, y con esta el proyecto funcionaba bien en django 1.10 ahora que hice upgrade es que tengo inconvenientes

Comment: Edita tu pregunta (puedes usar este enlace [edit]) y agrega todos los detalles que permita, sino reproducir, por lo menos comprender mejor tu problema. Sigue por favor esta guía: __[mcve]__.

Comment: Nelson, ¿y si borras esta pregunta? La otra se ve más completa y esta de cualquier como va a ser cerrada.